# incoporating maxlength into the jquery commafy function

Tags: jquery, regex

i have a numeric value box/field where users enter their property value, I have set the maxlength=7 for the field including 6 digits and one comma, I am using the jquery commafy function but i find that if a user holds the key down they can have up to 9 digits and 2 commas.

I am thinking a regular expression that works on keydown might fix it, if anyone knows how to fix this, please help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to validate it on blur.